# Geração de Expression para EF com propriedades dinâmicas

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Gostaria de realizar uma busca no `where` pelo **Entity Framework** passando o nome da propriedade que gostaria de comparar como uma `string`.

Por exemplo, tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class ClientData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public CLient CLient { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public int Shipments { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

E gostaria de criar um método da seguinte forma:

```
Expression<Func<ClientData, bool>> DynamicExpression(string propertyName, string value)
{
    Expression<Func<ClientData, bool>> predicate = _ =>
                                              _.Client.Name.ToUpper() == value.ToUpper();

    return predicate;
}
```

Porém em vez de usar diretamente **`Client.Name`** gostaria de fazer a comparação usando a propriedade referente ao nome que foi passado no parâmetro `propertyName`.

Isso é possível? Se sim, como poderia realizar isso?

Comment: Este código tem mais problemas do que imagina. Possível é, mas ficará lento. Com um contexto maior poderia fazer outras coisa completamente diferente, pode não ser anto quanto gostaria, mas seria uma solução bem melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O intuito é passar um código para que você tenha noção de como funciona isso por baixo dos panos, [código extraido - Dynamic Query Expressions With Entity Framework](https://nejcskofic.github.io/2017/03/20/dynamic-query-expressions-with-entity-framework/) e alterado uma pequena parte por mim para funcionar dados `nullable`, exemplo do código:

```
public static class Utils
{
    internal class PropertyAccessorCache<T> where T : class
    {
        private IDictionary<string, LambdaExpression> Cache { get; set; }
        public PropertyAccessorCache()
        {
            var storage = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();
            var t = typeof(T);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(t, "p");
            foreach (var property in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
                var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
                storage[property.Name] = lambdaExpression;
            }
            Cache = storage;
        }
        public LambdaExpression Get(string propertyName)
        {
            return Cache.TryGetValue(propertyName, out LambdaExpression result) ? result : null;
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyWhere<T, TValue>(this IQueryable<T> source,
        string propertyName,
        TValue propertyValue) where T : class
    {   
        var propertyAccessorCache = new PropertyAccessorCache<T>();
        var mba = propertyAccessorCache.Get(propertyName);
        if (mba == null) return source;           
        var eqe = Expression.Equal(mba.Body, Expression.Constant(propertyValue, mba.ReturnType));
        var expression = Expression.Lambda(eqe, mba.Parameters[0]);
        MethodCallExpression resultExpression = Expression.Call(null,
            GetMethodInfo(Queryable.Where, source, (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)null),
            new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(expression) });
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExpression);
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3> f, T1 unused1, T2 unused2)
         => f.Method;
}
```

observe que é um código extenso, e para pequenas soluções (que acho também desnecessário, mas vale como informação para o site) até dá para usar e isso é traduzido diretamente para SQL (testes realizados em ambiente Entity Framework Core e 6 com banco de dados SQLServer).

***Exemplo de uso:***

```
var peopleList = ctx.People.ApplyWhere("Name", "VALOR_EXEMPLO").ToList();
```

Esse trecho de código não cobre por exemplo um `LIKE`, etc, mas, responde o que a pergunta relata, vale lembrar que eu não faria isso, já visto que tudo isso já é previsto no Entity Framework, e talvez falte fazer o que precisa de outra forma, mas, fica como exemplo que acho bem válido.

<sup>***Referencia e direitos:***</sup>

- [Dynamic Query Expressions With Entity Framework](https://nejcskofic.github.io/2017/03/20/dynamic-query-expressions-with-entity-framework/)
- [Creating dynamic expression for entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346630/creating-dynamic-expression-for-entity-framework)